# Get clicked column index from row click

Tags: javascript

I have a row click event. Recently had to add a checkbox to each row. How can I identify the clicked cell on row click event?

Or prevent row click when clicked on the checkbox.

Attempts: this.parentNode.cellIndex is undefined on the row click event.

```js
function pop(row){
alert(row.cells[1].innerText);
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Site</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="pop(this);">
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="123456" /></td>
    <td>Lonodn</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You want a list of checked rows?

Comment: @zer00ne eventually yes, but not in this row click event.

Comment: a simple solution is to use double-click for row selection and single is then open to click on checkboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this? You can just check the `type` attribute of the source element of the event and validate whether to allow it or not, you can stop the event using `e.stopPropagation();return;`.

```js
function pop(e, row) {
console.log(e.srcElement.type);
  if(e.srcElement.type === 'checkbox'){
    e.stopPropagation();
    return;
  }else{
    console.log(row);
    alert(row.cells[1].innerText);
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Site</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="pop(event, this);">
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="123456" /></td>
    <td>Lonodn</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 You got the right idea @Naren Murali. A little hitch though. The alert still pops even I click on the checkbox right?. I will use your code and  try to fix it. Cheers!

Comment: @Prosper The problem is it does not appear when you click exactly in the checkbox, else it considers it as another element, you need to add a div bigger than the checkbox, set some attribute for the containing `td` tag, then check if the attribute exists, then the `td` tag contains a checkbox!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass in the event details to your function and check the `target` property:

```js
function pop(e){
    // If the target is not a checkbox...
    if(!e.target.matches("input[type='checkbox']")) {
        alert(e.target.cellIndex);
    }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Site</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="pop(event)">
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="123456" /></td>
    <td>Lonodn</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** If you have nested elements inside the `<td>`, you might want to check `e.target.closest("td")` instead.

**Note 2:** You might need a polyfill for the [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) method depending on which browsers you're supporting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example if you don't want to attach a listener on every row :

```js
document.getElementById("majorCities").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target.type === 'checkbox'){
  var checked = e.target.checked;
 var tr = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
 var city = tr.cells[1].innerHTML;
 console.log(city+":checked="+checked);
  }

});
```

```html
<table id="majorCities" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Site</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td>London</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td>Paris</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td>New-York</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.pop = function(row){
    console.log('here');
    var parent = row.parentNode;
  Array.from(row.parentNode.querySelectorAll('tr')).forEach(function(tr, index){
    if (tr === row) {
        alert(index)
    }
  })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sz42oyvm/

Comment: Thanks, but I need to identify the clicked column index, not the row index I am afraid. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is for the pleasure, another example with an object containing the cities' names and a method to draw the table with ids corresponding to the name of the clicked city, so getting the clicked name is easier.

```js
(function () {
var mySpace = window || {};
mySpace.cities = {};
mySpace.cities.pointer = document.getElementById("majorCities");
mySpace.cities.names = ["Select","City"];
mySpace.cities.data = [{"name":"Paris"},{"name":"New Delhi"},{"name":"Washington"},{"name":"Bangkok"},{"name":"Sydney"}];

mySpace.cities.draw = function(){
this.pointer.innerHTML="";
var html = "";
html+="<tr>"
 for(var i=0;i < this.names.length;i++){
  html+="<th>"+this.names[i];
  html+="</th>"
 }
html+="</tr>"
 for(var i=0;i < this.data.length;i++){
  html+="<tr>"
  html+="<td><input id='"+this.data[i].name+"' type='checkbox'/></td>"
  html+="<td>"+this.data[i].name+"</td>" 
  html+="</tr>"
 }
this.pointer.innerHTML=html;
}
mySpace.cities.draw();
mySpace.cities.pointer.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target.type === 'checkbox'){
 var checked = e.target.checked;
 var city = e.target.id;
 console.log(city+":checked="+checked);
  }

});

})();
```

```css
 table {width:25%;background:#ccc;border:1px solid black;text-align:left;}
 td,tr {background:white;}
 th:first-of-type{width:20%;}
```

```html
<table id="majorCities">

</table>
```